# как преобразовать object в int64 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

как преобразовать столбец "data" из object в int64,  вот данные [df](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/xx6HN4KcGtrPlA)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel("df.xlsx")

# пробую так, но выдает ошибку.
df["data"].values.astype(np.int64)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-143-763b952fb481>", line 1, in <module>
    df["data"].values.astype(np.int64)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 246'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [pd.to_numeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df["new"] = pd.to_numeric(df["data"].str.replace(r"[^\d\-]", ""), errors="coerce")
```

Comment: в новых "new" данных минусы отбросились, а они нужны. @MaxU

Comment: @VEL, исправил ответ. На будущее советую всегда приводить в вопросе небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: спасибо, совет учту.@MaxU

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо "MaxU" за предоставленный метод, в сымитированной задачи в этой он сработал, но когда перенес его(код) на рабочею задачу, то выскочила ошибка:

(AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!)

Помогло решить эту ошибку не большое дополнение к коду, вот решение которое у меня сработало.

```
df["new"] = pd.to_numeric(df["data"].astype(str).str.replace(r"[^\d\-]", ""), errors="coerce")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def make_data(data):

    if data == '...'
        return 1
    elif data == '...'
         return 2
    return 3
```

Как по мне лучше воспользоваться таким способом.

Comment: То есть, если будут строки числами от "1" до "1000", то нужно будет 998 раз написать elif, я правильно понял вашу идею?